# copying files on remote mounts

Tags: linux, mount

I'm facing an issue with a cephfs mounted on a linux machine on power hardware.

The os installed on the power machine is suse linux enterprise. I'm successfully mounting the fs, ls works fine, I can create empty files with touch. When trying to copy a file that contains data, it get's stuck, same happens with dd.

The tricky part is that if I firstly create the empty file on the mount, for example test.img and then use dd to write inside, it works without any issue.

In the kernel logs there is nothing useful.

Did you ever saw something like this before?

Comment: How do you define the size of that empty file you create? Writing into a mounted file system with the `dd` command is a pretty uncommon idea...

Comment: "When trying to copy a file that contains data, it get's stuck, same happens with dd."  Even if I try to copy a file, I cannot write it in the mount, only if I first create the empty file with the same name as the file I'm about to copy.

Comment: To answer the question I used dd for testing purpose, specifying the file size that will be create, the write speed t and so on.

Comment: That means you write into an unreserved area of the mounted file system. That will cause issues.

Comment: Aha, now I understand what you're saying :) dd is able to write a file as well, like this: dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/test.img bs=50M count=10 it's creating a 500M file called test.img ;)